# Как взаимодействовать с элементами через касания? (touch events)

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, touch-event

Что-то вроде "пилю портфолио". Хотелось бы, чтобы меню на мобильных устройствах открывалось и закрывалось по свайпу вправо и влево соответственно.

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {

    var x = event.touches[0].clientX;

    window.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {

        var deltaX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX - x;

        if (deltaX > x + 100) {
            showMenu();

        } else if (deltaX < x - 100) {
            hideMenu();

        }

    });
});
```

мне думалось, что такая конструкция будет рабочей, но нет.

Comment: Попробуй почитать здесь:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374184/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0