# Как реализовать свайп блока?

Tags: javascript, html

На скриншоте можно увидеть тонкую полосу. Ее можно убрать свайпом пальцем вниз.
Как это реализовать в js?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал это путём `touchmove` и `touchend` в `addEventListener`, а также вместо `display: none` стал бы использовать `opacity: 0`, так как его можно анимировать.

```js
const line = document.querySelector('.line')
const main = document.querySelector('.main')
main.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  // Для ПК
  line.style.opacity = 0
  main.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 30px)'
})
main.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  // Для ПК
  main.style.transform = 'none'
  line.style.opacity = 1
})
main.addEventListener('touchmove', () => {
  // Для моб. девайсов
  line.style.opacity = 0
  main.style.transform = 'translate(0px, 30px)'
})
main.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
  // Для моб. девайсов
  main.style.transform = 'none'
  line.style.opacity = 1
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
}

.line {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50px;
  transition: opacity 600ms ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p>Попробуйте потащить</p>
  </div>
</div>
```